# Don't match if the operation contain different variable

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I want to match an addition which contain same variable using regex.

**Example 1**

> **String:**
>
> 5p+3p
>
> **Result:**
>
> 5p+3p

**Example 2**

> **String:**
>
> 5AB+3AB
>
> **Result:**
>
> 5AB+3AB

**Example 3**

> **String:**
>
> 5AB+3BA
>
> **Result:**
>
> 5AB+3BA

**Example 4:**

> **String:**
>
> 5p+3q
>
> **Result:**
>
> nothing (doesn't match at all)

I have created my own regex below:

`(\d+)(\w+)\+(\d+)(\w+)`

However my regex doesn't fulfill the last condition above.

Comment: You may have to build syntax tree if this question is a small piece of a generalized question.

Comment: Try something like https://regex101.com/r/G73kFb/2, but it is not quite scalable.

Comment: @mario It doesn't has spaces and another character except alphabet. Wiktor, yeah that's the result that I want. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could combine a regex with an additional check:

```
/**
 * Checks a given string operation and only returns it if it's valid.
 * 
 * @param string $operation
 * @return string|null
 */
function checkOperation(string $operation): ?string
{
  // Make sure the operation looks valid (adjust if necessary)
  if (!preg_match('/^\d+([a-zA-Z]+)\+\d+([a-zA-Z]+)$/', $operation, $matches)) {
    return null;
  }

  // Make sure the left and right variables have the same characters
  if (array_count_values(str_split($matches[1])) != array_count_values(str_split($matches[2]))) {
    return null;
  }

  return $operation;
}
```

**Demo: https://3v4l.org/iS8Ih**

Comment: This function is easy to applied for my own needed. Thank you.